# Compare avg of data in column of certain users against a another user in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
retID             Mnth           CollectYear       LW
ZZDZZ_Z            1                2015           102
ZZDZZ_Z            2                2015           100
ZZDZZ_Z            3                2015             99
ZZDZZ_Z            4                2015             99
ZZDZZ_Z            5                2015             98
ZZDZZ_Z            6                2015             99
ZZDZZ_Z            7                2015           100
ZZDZZ_Z            8                2015           101
ZZDZZ_Z            9                2015           102
ZZDZZ_Z           10                2015           102
ZZDZZ_Z           11                2015           103
ZZDZZ_Z           12                2015           104
c26_GW              8               2015           108
c26_GW              9               2015           102
c26_GW            10                2015           104
c24_HOF             8               2015           101
c24_HOF             9               2015           103
c24_HOF           10                2015            98
```

I need to have the value for RetID ZZDZZ_Z in any one month against the avg for the other retID's in the same month that are not ZZDZZ_Z.

Sorry for having to post again, trying to over simplify.

Comment: What you have tried so far post your attempts too. Simply learn using functions like `avg()`, `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    select avg(case when user in (1,2) then trans end) Avgtrans
         , avg(case when user = 3 then trans end) user3Trans
         , Month 
      from (...)
  group by Month
```

This is ANSI SQL and works in Oracle, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server and Teradata; I'm not 100% sure about mySQL, but it should function there, too.

Comment: I tried to simplify my question and your answer gave the desired result, but when I used the same query again my actual table the result was wrong. I have amended the question to reflect my real table

Comment: Well, actually you didn't over-simplify. The solution pattern is just the same. You might want to try and work out the transfer to your actual table for yourself; it is a small step.

Comment: You are correct, I had more data in my table than from my example so just needed to group differently and all is OK. Thank you your help